# Checking the positivity of elements entered by the user in an array

Tags: arrays, c, while-loop, infinite-loop, do-while

I have a program which asks user to enter elements that will be assigned into an array. But i want to check the entered number is whether positive or negative. If there is a negative number program should warn to user and asks user to enter positive numbers again. I wrote my code but it goes into a infinite loop.
How can make it correct?

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    
   int A[MAX] = {};
   int n,jj;
   


    printf("How many numbers do you want to enter?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);


    for (jj=0; jj<n; jj++)
        {

            printf(" enter the %d. number\n", (jj+1));
            scanf("%d",&A[jj]);

            while(A[jj]<=0){

                printf("Please enter only positive numbers");
            }

        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are the variables n and jj declared?

Comment: As it is part of a bigger program i cut some part of code but forgot these variables. I added again. @VladfromMoscow

Comment: OT: you should format your code properly.

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters this initialization using an empty braced list

```
int A[MAX] = {};
```

is incorrect in C. You have to write

```
int A[MAX] = { 0 };
```

It is evident that this loop

```
while(A[jj]<=0){

    printf("Please enter only positive numbers");
}
```

is an infinite loop when `A[jj]` is not positive. So what you do is what you get.

Instead you could write for example

```
    for (jj=0; jj<n; jj++)
    {

        printf(" enter the %d. number\n", (jj+1));
        
        do
        {
            scanf("%d",&A[jj]);

            if ( A[jj]<=0 )
            {
                printf("Please enter only positive numbers");
            }
        } while ( A[jj] <= 0 );

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the infinite loop is due to the use of  `while(A[jj]<=0)`

The problem can be solved in these 2 steps:

1. read user input into a temporary variable.
2. Assign the temporary variable to array element, only if the value is positive.

**Here is the working code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

int main() {
    
   int A[MAX] = {};
   int n, jj, temp = 0;
   
    printf("How many numbers do you want to enter?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);


    for (jj = 0; jj < n; jj++) {

            printf("Enter the # %d number : ", (jj+1));
            scanf("%d",&temp);
            if (temp < 0) {
                printf("Negative number will not be accepted. Please try again\n");
                --jj;
                continue;
            }
            A[jj] = temp;
        }

return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
How many numbers do you want to enter?
3
Enter the # 1 number : 1
Enter the # 2 number : -2
Negative number will not be accepted. Please try again
Enter the # 2 number : 2
Enter the # 3 number : 3
```

Comment: that makes sense